# Which software could I use to build an app that shows data saved in excel files?

Tags: java, python, xml

First of all, I would like to thank you for welcoming me.

To put you in context I want to design a programme to show data visualy and to make some reports. As soon as the design is finalized the customer will be able to use it in his own PC (server, etc..). Therefore, I would like to make it in a profesional way.

The programme will read the data from XML files.

So, I would like to know which option fits more to my proposal mentioned above.

Regarding my programming skills I have basic level using Java and Python.

I want to thank you in advance for your collaboration.

Yours Sincerely,

Guillermo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you know Python, take a look at the excellent online eBook "Automate the Boring Stuff with Python".

[Chapter 12 – Working with Excel Spreadsheets](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter12/) although personally I don't work with Excel directly. I prefer a manual step of exporting from Excel as CSV, in which case, see

[Chapter 14 – Working with CSV Files and JSON Data](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter14/)

---

The rest of the book is very useful too

Chapter 0 – Introduction
Chapter 1 – Python Basics
Chapter 2 – Flow Control
Chapter 3 – Functions
Chapter 4 – Lists
Chapter 5 – Dictionaries and Structuring Data
Chapter 6 – Manipulating Strings
Chapter 7 – Pattern Matching with Regular Expressions
Chapter 8 – Reading and Writing Files
Chapter 9 – Organizing Files
Chapter 10 – Debugging
Chapter 11 – Web Scraping
Chapter 12 – Working with Excel Spreadsheets
Chapter 13 – Working with PDF and Word Documents
Chapter 14 – Working with CSV Files and JSON Data
Chapter 15 – Keeping Time, Scheduling Tasks, and Launching Programs
Chapter 16 – Sending Email and Text Messages
Chapter 17 – Manipulating Images
Chapter 18 – Controlling the Keyboard and Mouse with GUI Automation

---

> I want to design a programme to show data visualy and to make some reports

Look into [wxPython](https://wxpython.org) , the cross-platform GUI toolkit for the Python language. With wxPython software developers can create truly native user interfaces for their Python applications, that run with little or no modifications on Windows, Macs and Linux or other Unix-like systems.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. Very kind of you to share your knowledge :). With all this information I can start working. 

Yours sinceresly,

Comment: Good luck, Guillemo :-)  If you have any problems coding it, you can post your code and ask for help on https://stackoverflow.com/   Btw, if this answered your question, please clcik the tick to accept the answer. That will help others who read this in future.

Answer (score 2):

I would also suggest taking a look at [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) which is a Python library for Data Analysis that includes the ability to read and write Excel files (as well as a lot more).

pandas is well suited for many different kinds of data:

- Tabular data with heterogeneously-typed columns, as in an SQL table or Excel spreadsheet
- Ordered and unordered (not necessarily fixed-frequency) time series data
- Arbitrary matrix data (homogeneously typed or heterogeneous) with row and column labels
- Any other form of observational / statistical data sets. The data   actually need not be labeled at all to be placed into a pandas data structure.

For a native looking, cross-platform & commercially distributable GUI library use wxPython.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. Very kind of you to share your knowledge :). I'll start with WxPython that you recommend to me both, and then later I'll try parallel with Pandas. 

Your Sincerely,